# How can I access the result in Derived 1 and Derived 2 and not the base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

```
class Baseclass
{
    public void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
    }
}
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{
    new void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " ");
    }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    new void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived2 d = new Derived2();

        Derived1 e = new Derived1();
        d.fun();
        e.fun();
    }
}
```

How can I access the result in Derived 1 and Derived 2 and not the base class
Is this overloading or overriding?

Comment: use *virtual* keyword in the base class method and *override* it in the derived classes. BTW there is no result to access on a void method

Comment: What @SirRufo said is exactly what you need. Just to add some value, why did you use 'new' keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` is neither overloading nor overriding. It essentially says 'When I am called, *and the object is cast as `Derived1`*, then invoke this'. Note that it's *when the object is cast*, rather than whenever the object is interacted with.

Your code would *appear* to work, if you had marked the methods as `public`. For example:

```
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{
    public new void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " ");
    }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public new void fun()
    {
        Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
    }
}
```

Would print

> Derived2 class Derived1 class

However, changing your code to the following will reveal the problem with `new` in this case:

```
void Main()
{
    Derived2 d = new Derived2();

    Derived1 e = new Derived1();
    ExecuteIt(d);
    ExecuteIt(e);
}

void ExecuteIt(Baseclass obj)
{
    obj.fun();
}
```

Prints

> Base class Base class

Since the object is cast as `Baseclass`, and thus the hiding doesn't take effect. To properly implement overriding, you need to do the following:

```
class Baseclass
{
    public virtual void fun()
    //     ^^^^^^^
    {
        Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
    }
}
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{
    public override void fun()
//  ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    {
        Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " ");
    }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public override void fun()
//  ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    {
        Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
    }
}
```

Which, when run with:

```
void Main()
{
    Derived2 d = new Derived2();

    Derived1 e = new Derived1();
    ExecuteIt(d);
    ExecuteIt(e);
}

void ExecuteIt(Baseclass obj)
{
    obj.fun();
}
```

Properly outputs

> Derived2 class Derived1 class

Comment: thanks , i figured it out.. Ive got question, virtual and override keywords are partners right? abstract and override keyword are partners too?

Comment: Can i have a same procedure in override method and in virtual. e.g, virtual say yes , override say no OR virtual say no then override say no too

Comment: @JohnMasqued I'm not sure partners is the correct word, but yes - you can only override abstract or virtual members. I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment, but if you're asking if it's possible to grab the parent result, then yes: you'd call `base.fun()`

Comment: is there such this as public string abstract?

Comment: do you have an email , i can ask questions too? ,your answers are really sane